# Regex to match file extension while ignoring query string

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewrite-module

I'd like to build a IIS url rewrite rule that matches several file extensions but ignore the query string.

Samples:

```
/hello.html // Match
/test?qs=world.html // Should not match
/test?qs=world.html&qs2=x // Should not match
```

Here is what I was using that does not work correctly:

```
<add matchType="Pattern" input="{HTTP_URL}" pattern=".+\.(js|css|less|html|eot|svg|ttf|woff|json|xml)$" negate="true" /> <!--Any url with a dot for file extension-->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\w+` instead of `.+` .................(`\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`):

```
<add matchType="Pattern" input="{HTTP_URL}" pattern="\w+\.(js|css|less|html|eot|svg|ttf|woff|json|xml)$" negate="true" /> <!--Any url with a dot for file extension-->
```

If you want to allow other characters (non included in `\w`) and still ignore query string you can use `[^?]+` instead of `.+`

Comment: this won't match `/hello.html?foo=bar`

Answer (score 0):

see if this works for you:

I write it in javascript, (I don't know IIS) but the regex is always similar

```
    /^.*\/[\w]+\.[\w]{2,4}$/.test('/test?qs=world.html') // return false
/^.*\/[\w]+\.[\w]{2,4}$/.test('/world.html') // return true
```

maybe it work as:

```
    <add matchType="Pattern" input="{HTTP_URL}" pattern="^.*\/[\w]+\.[\w]{2,4}$" negate="true" />
```

but I put the extension as a generic way. if you want to make a whitebox test for extension, you may replace it to:

```
^.*\/[\w]+\.(js|css|less|html|eot|svg|ttf|woff|json|xml)$
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this will work in IIS: `^[^?]*$` will match any string not containing a `?`.